# Finding a file which has "info" in its title

Tags: ls

By using the ls command I can list the names of all the files in the directory I am working with. However, how do I list all of the files in the directory which have contained **in their title** info? So a file titled zoneinfo would be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls *info*`

This should list all files in this directory which have *info* anywhere in their name.

Comment: it will also list the contents of subdirectories with 'info' in the name.  use `ls -d *info*` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: @cas Are you saying that any sub directory with info in its title will also be listed when using the `ls *info*` command? And using `ls -d *info*` only lists the files with info in their title?

Comment: If you use `-d` directories with will be listed with their names. Without `-d` the content of those directories will be listed instead.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the `find` command:

```
find `pwd` -name '*info*' -type f
```

Remove `-type f` which limits the listing to files only if you want directories listed as well.

Comment: Why do you need 'pwd' here?

Comment: `pwd` will prepend the results found by find with the current working directory.